# How to judge the relative prestige of named postdoctoral fellowships?

Tags: funding, postdocs, job-search

I see more and more named postdoctoral fellowships being advertised — sometimes funded by departments, sometimes by universities, and sometimes by government agencies or NGOs. I often notice recipients of such fellowships (or their PIs) claiming that they were awarded "the prestigious fellowship X", but I can't help but think that if everything is prestigious, then nothing is.

How to judge the relative prestige of such fellowships?

Comment: This is verbal fluff. Unless you already know the fellowship in question is prestigious by your standards, just ignore the claim.

Comment: And why would you think there is any reasonable scale on which to judge "relative" prestige? Seems more like a vast space of possibilities, not any approximately linear ranking.

Comment: Why would you want to judge them? What is your position? Are you filtering interview candidates?

Comment: @user111388 I am not filtering candidates, just wanted to hear some opinions about it. Are the criteria different depending on who is judging? I would expect a fellowship applicant and a hiring committee to judge the fellowships' prestige in the same way, so the question can be answered from either perspective.

Comment: @Pyem: My point is: Some people have to judge candidates (hiring comittees). Other people (researchers, common citizens etc) do not have to. my opinion is that if one does not have a strong reason to judge people, one should refrain from it: what is the point to rank people?

Comment: Someone willing to drop 300 grand on your student is prestigious no matter where the funding comes from. I don't know why you'd need to stratify that group when most people won't get those fellowships.

Comment: One (imperfect) indicator for competitive postdoc positions is the acceptance rate. For example, my postdoc position is named (local national science foundation) and the acceptance rate is about 15%. You need a pretty good application, which is quite comprehensive, and you get about 250k-300k EUR to work on your own project which you designed. I would say locally this is a pretty prestigious fellowship because people know what it entails. Of course, as in any grant application process there is considerable randomness involved.